# rename or replace all urls in html file per javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace, intel-xdk

I have a jquerymobile web app and want to keep all existing hundreds of different external url links in the html file like

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" data-rel="external">Link</a>
```

but want to make them behave like this:

```
<a href="javascript:intel.xdk.device.launchExternal('http://www.example.com');">
```

How would I do that (without search and replace) with a script?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to add an event handler for all links, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    this.href = "javascript:intel.xdk.device.launchExternal('" + this.href + "');";
});
```

The job will be done only when the link is clicked.

Or, thanks to [bencol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980692/benkol):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    javascript:intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You should adjust for the fact that user might click two times.

Comment: You can also try:
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(this.href);
    });

Comment: @Tewr you mean double click?

Comment: @matewka: no, just two clicks. in your first example the second click will result in something like href="javascript:intel...('javascript:intel..('[url]')')"

Comment: @Tewr you're right. But I assumed that the `intel.xdk.device.launchExternal` function does the page redirect. Anyway, I suggest the second solution, suggested by benkol.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery or jquery mobile, use this to replace all links

```
$(function() {
    $("a").each(function() { 
        $(this).attr("href", "javascript:intel...('" + $(this).attr("href") +"')"); 
    });
});
```