# Add div data inside onclick dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, intel-xdk

Trying to get the data from a div inside onclick event dynamically

```
<div id="buyprint"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="intel.xdk.device.launchExternal('#buyprint');">Buy Print</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate? Your question is not very clear. You show an empty div.

```
<a href="javascript:void;" (instead of #) is one place to start.
```

Comment: The div have links i want to add dynamically to the onclick event `$('#buyprint').html(); `

Comment: `$("#buyprint").on('click', 'a', function() {
    javascript:intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(this.href);
    return false;
});`

Comment: check here: [rename-or-replace-all-urls-in-html-file-per-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832869/rename-or-replace-all-urls-in-html-file-per-javascript)

Comment: Tried it but it didnt work.  I am looking for something like this `<a href="#" onclick="intel.xdk.device.launchExternal('blink');">Buy Print</a>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#buyprint", function() {  
var blink = $('#buyprint').html(); 
}; 
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do but this will give you the content of your div.

```
  document.getElementById('buyprint').innerHTML;
```